# How to subclass UIbutton and add a few variables

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to write a class that inherits from UIbutton, with an init that passes in more attributes, as shown in code below, but there is always be an error, please help me to solve it.

Alternatively is there another way of achieving the effect.
this is first time wrong screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43S5B.png)and then i try answer code Can compile successfully, but at runtime error, I've updated the above screenshot of error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moOqW.png)
Thank you very much

```
import UIKit

class myButton:UIButton {

    var x = 0
    var y = 0
    var Px = 0
    var Py = 0
    var g = 0.0
    var f = 999.5
    var cango: Bool
    var zuobiao = [0,0]


    init(x: Int, y: Int,Px: Int,Py: Int,g:Double,f:Double,cango:Bool,zuobiao:[Int]){
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.Px = Px
        self.Py = Py
        self.g = g
        self.f = f
        self.cango = cango
        self.zuobiao = zuobiao
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: I have edited to try to clarify what you are after but it is very difficult to tell. Can you please check my edit and clarify further if necessary. In particular, if there is an error please provide the error text and location in your code where it occurs.

Comment: If you need help with an error you must tell us the error and the line number on which it occurs or we can't help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was the first question here, is the error screenshot uploaded now

Answer (score 0):

simple solution of your question is using `init(frame: CGRect)`

```
class myButton: UIButton {
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
    var px = 0
    var py = 0
    var g = 0.0
    var f = 999.5
    var cango: Bool
    var zuobiao = [0, 0]

    init(frame: CGRect, x: Int, y: Int, px: Int, py: Int, g: Double, f: Double , cango: Bool, zuobiao: [Int]) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.px = px
        self.py = py
        self.g = g
        self.f = f
        self.cango = cango
        self.zuobiao = zuobiao
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

but It looks need to refactor variables...

Comment: Thank you for your help，i use your code, Can compile successfully, but at runtime error,  fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")  The error in this place,  I've updated the above screenshot

Comment: If you override init(frame:), you need to include init(coder:). If you work with Xcode much along with their build errors, this is easily fixed by letting Xcode include it.